# How to create two dropable using jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I m new to Jquery UI drag-drop and sortable,
I want to create one list and one container, specific elements from the list can we drop to the container like element1 and element2.
After dropping elements to the container it will make another dropable container inside the previous dropable container.
from list remaining elements can be put inside this new container now.

currently, i m able to drag and drop elements from list to container,
Needed help for other features, I read API documentation of jquery UI drag-drop and sortable, did not get anything from it.

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use examples of jquery UI its well Documented

Comment: @AjeetKumar hi Ajeet thanks for the reply I try to find examples but did not find any convenient example.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ you can go by this link. there are many examples. Use it according to your logics

Comment: @AjeetKumar thanks man.